# Postfix Server - Wordpress

Tags: server, configuration, mail, postfix, wordpress

I have installed postfix on my Ubuntu server. I want it to send mail to my subscribers on the blog. I have installed the SMTP plugin for wordpress so its not using php mail. But any time anybody signs up to the blog so they can comment i get a error in my mail.log file.

```
disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

No idea. It just wont send any mail. The test mail seems to work all the time without TLS and sometimes without it. Its flaky. The plugin is a good one and is used on lots of blogs and sites so there is no problem with that.

[image]

This is the settings for the plugin. And the test email at the top works if I fire one off to my gmail account. No idea why it wont work when people sign up to the blog though? Mus be something in my Postfix configs but then why does it work when sending a test mail?

Any ideas thanks?

EDIT: This is a test of MX records on mxtoolbox.com

[image]

Comment: I'm not a postfix expert, but with a local smtp server install it should definitely work with the default wordpress configuration. You can safely reset your default mail settings in wordpress. This is probably a postfix configuration issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your Postfix working correctly?

On a console try:

> telnet localhost 25

After you have established the connection to your postfix mail server type

> ehlo localhost

If you see the lines

`250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH`

among others, everything is working.

Type quit to return to the system's shell.

Comment: SMTP is working correctly. According to the telnet response so it appears that it must be a problem with the plugin. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first step is configuring postfix correctly. Once you can `telnet localhost 25` then you need to configure this plugin with a user on your Ubuntu box that can send mail with their corresponding password. Once that works, setup TLS. You do need to use SMTP auth though...otherwise you open yourself up to a open relay.